# Можно ли использовать сервис в таком формате?

Tags: javascript, angular

Мне пришлось работать со специалистом в команде, который пытается подбить меня использовать построенные им сервисы. Но что-то мне синтаксис такой не нравится и вызывает ступор. Может быть я отстал от прогресса, что это за зверства такие? Поправьте меня, но это же на мой взгляд bad practice.

```
// Обращение к сервису из компонента
initItem() {
  this.availableActions = {
    Purchased: this.siteService.getClientDetails().RegistryItemSupportPurchasedInStore,
    ChipIn: this.siteService.getClientDetails().RegistryItemSupportChipIn,
    GiftIt: this.siteService.getClientDetails().RegistryItemSupportGiftIt
}



// Сам сервис выглядит как-то так
getClientDetails(): M.ClientDetails {
  return this.clientDetails;
}

initSite(siteId: number): Observable<void> {
  return new Observable<void>(o => {
    this.net.getClientDetails(siteId).subscribe(clientDetails => {
        this.clientDetails = clientDetails;

        // Init feature configuration

        o.next();
        o.complete();
    });
  });
}
```

Меня напрягает прежде всего вот эта вот конструкция:
`this.siteService.getClientDetails().RegistryItemSupportChipIn`

Выходит, что каждое свойство объекта притягивается через шпагат из сервиса.

Comment: а ты как хотел использовать?

Comment: Я привык, что притягиваешь полный объект в компоненту, а затем уже используешь его как объект, а не каждый раз дергаешь сервис.

`this.clientDetails = this.siteService.getClientDetails()`

`this.clientDetails.name`
`this.clientDetails.id...`

Answer (score 0):

Если очень важна любая возможная производительность - лучше сделать один запрос компонента, и работать с ним, если нет, то можно и так.

Если это все поля, то можно просто this.obj = service.getObj().